# Supposed to be global Tkinter-window 'not defined'

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have written a little tool that simulates a traffic light system with a GUI. Worked fine on Windows with Python 2.7, but since it was intended to run on a Raspberry Pi where it was necessary to re-write the threading-part.

So I am trying to put most of the stuff into one method. But still I am not able to create a Tkinter-element from outside the method where the Tkinter-window was built. Can someone tell me how to fix the code so that it is possible to create elements from another methode? Here's the code:

```
class GUI (threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global window
        window = Tk()
        window.title('Ampel GUI')
        window = Canvas(window, width=400, height=200)
        window.pack()

        button1 = Button(window, text="Press", command=lambda: pushbutton(25))
        button1.pack()
        button1.place(x=190, y=70)

        button2 = Button(window, text="Press", command=lambda: pushbutton(12))
        button2.pack()
        button2.place(x=115, y=160)

        (...)

        window.mainloop()

    @staticmethod
    def output(lampe, status):
        if status == 0:
            if lampe == 21:
                window.create_oval(140, 30, 160, 10, fill="#FFA6A6")

            if lampe == 20:
                window.create_oval(170, 30, 190, 10, fill="#FAFAAA")

    (...)

output(20,0)
```

and this is what I get:

```
line 120, in output
window.create_oval(170, 30, 190, 10, fill="#FAFAAA")
NameError: global name 'window' is not defined
```

What should I do to create the oval as intended?

Comment: tkinter isn't thread safe. You shouldn't call any widget methods from any thread except the one that creates the root window.

Comment: Since you are using threading, have you considered the possibility that the code that generates the error is running before the code that defines the variable?